# How to show markdown field on index in Laravel nova?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a nova model named "Note" with the following field method

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable()->hideFromIndex(),

        Markdown::make('Note')
            ->rules('required', 'string'),
    ];
}
```

In the index page I can only see ID of table. Any idea on how to display Markdown field in index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the attribute `showOnIndex` to `true`.

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    $noteField = Markdown::make('Note');
    $noteField->showOnIndex = true;

    return [
        ID::make()->sortable()->hideFromIndex(),

        $noteField->rules('required', 'string'),
    ];
}
```

Comment: As of v1.1.8, this doesn't work, returning the error that the property showOnIndex doesn't exist.

Comment: @Grayda I'm currently on version 1.1.7, I'll check if there any alternative on version 1.1.8

Answer (score 1):

As of the current version of Nova (Aug 2023) this is still not directly possible. A potential workaround to consider (which I use myself) is to use a Text field only on the index, and use the Markdown field everywhere else. An example using your original code:

```
[
        ID::make()->sortable()->hideFromIndex(),

        Text::make('Note')->onlyOnIndex(),

        /* ->hideFromIndex() is redundant here because Markdown won't show anyway */
        Markdown::make('Note')->rules('required','string')/*->hideFromIndex()*/,
]
```

The only caveat of the above example of course is that the text field won't format your markdown code using markdown, so you'll see the raw content instead of the pretty formatted markdown output.

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2020 (and verified June 2022),
the answer is:

**A:** You ***can't*** show a `Markdown` field on an index page

---

Source:

laravel/nova-issues #2464, [Markdown field doesn't display correctly on index page](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/2464#issuecomment-607934787) asked for the same thing.
Laravel employee's response:

> Markdown fields are not meant to be shown on the index.